# Alexander modules and weight filtrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, mixed-hodge-structure

$\def\Ext{\mathrm{Ext}}$I have the following situation: I have a complex algebraic variety $X$. I want to compute the weight filtration on various abelian covers $Y \to X$. As a concrete example, take $X = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (x_1, x_2) : x_1 x_2 = 1 \}$ and let $Y_{\ell}$ be the cover where we adjoin an $\ell$-th root of $x_1 x_2 - 1$. Topologically, $X$ retracts onto the locus $\{ |x_1| = |x_2|,\ |x_1 x_2-1| = 1 \}$, which is a pinched $2$-sphere, and $Y_{\ell}$ retracts onto a "necklace" of $\ell$ $2$-spheres. One can compute that $Y_{\ell}$ has betti numbers $(1,1,\ell)$ with $H^1$ in weight $2$, and $H^2$ splitting up into one piece in weight $4$ and the rest in weight $2$. See [Section 7.1 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06843) for the details.

It is natural to organize our data in the following way. Let $A = H_1(X, \mathbb{Z})$, so abelian covers of $X$ come with an action of $A$. For any character $\chi$ of $A$, let $H^{p, \chi}(X)$ be the $\chi$ component of $H^{\ast}(Y, \mathbb{C})$ where $Y$ is any abelian cover of $X$ such that the image of $H_1(Y)$ in $H_1(X)$ is contained in $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$. This is unaltered by passing to a larger cover $Z$ since, for any finite $G$-cover $Z \to Y$, we have $H^{\ast}(Y, \mathbb{C}) \cong H^{\ast}(Z, \mathbb{C})^G$. Moreover, it is well defined to speak of the weight filtration on $H^{\ast, \chi}(X, \mathbb{C})$. In the above example, $H^{0,0} = H^{1,0} = \mathbb{C}$, in weights $0$ and $2$; $H^{2,\chi}$ is one dimensional for all $\chi$, with weight $4$ if $\chi$ is trivial and weight $2$ otherwise.

I was talking with a topologist, and he told me I should organize the data as follows (errors in this are my own). Let $R$ be the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[A]$. Let $X^{ab}$ be the universal abelian cover of $X$ and let $M_p = H_p(X^{ab}, \mathbb{C})$. Then $M_p$ is an $R$-module called the Alexander module, and it is finitely generated. Let $L_{\chi}$ be $\mathbb{C}$ considered as an $R$-module where $A$ acts by $\chi$. Then there is a spectral sequence relating $H^{\ast,\chi}$ and $\Ext^{\ast}_R(M_{\ast}, L_{\chi})$. (This is basically the universal coefficient theorem.)

In the example I gave, $A = \mathbb{Z}$ so $R$ is the Laurent polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[z^{\pm}]$. The abelian cover $X^{ab}$ is an infinite chain of spheres so $H_0$ is one dimensional, $H_1$ vanishes and $H_2 \cong \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. As $R$-modules, we have $M_0 \cong L_1 \cong R/(z-1)$, $M_1 = 0$ and $M_2 \cong R$. We have 
$$\Ext^0(M_0, L_{\chi}) = \Ext^1(M_0, L_{\chi}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{C} & \chi = 1 \\ 0 & \chi \neq 1 \end{cases}$$
and
$$\Ext^0(M_2, L_{\chi}) \cong \mathbb{C}$$
for all $\chi$. So this predicts the dimensions exactly.

But what extra data on $M_2$ do I need to see that $\Ext^0(M_2, L_1)$ is in weight $4$, while $\Ext^0(M_2, L_{\chi})$ is in weight $2$ for all other $\chi$?

Comment: I just ran across the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01589 , whose abstract suggests it answers this question. When I have digested the paper (which may be some time) I'll try to write a summary here.